# std::vector of std::functions find

Tags: c++, c++11

I have a vector populated with callback functions and I would like to check whether callback to the function already exists prior to adding it. I don't know whether it will even work bu so far it doesn't even compile.

```
vector<std::function<void(void*)>> _callbacks;

void Event::RegisterCallback(std::function<void(void*)> callback)
{
    if (callback == NULL)
        return;

    vector<std::function<void(void*)>>::iterator it = std::find(_callbacks.begin(), _callbacks.end(), callback);

    if (it == _callbacks.end())
    {
        _callbacks.push_back(callback);
    }
    else
    {
        //print error
        throw;
    }
}
```

This gives a compile error:
"Overload resolution selected deleted operator '=='" in alorithm(805). This is related to the find function call.

How do I get this to work and is it even going to compare function calls to the same method properly?

Thanks

Comment: `std::function` doesn't implement `operator==`. You can't compare them, so you can't `std::find` them either.

Comment: Even if it did compile, it would never find anything. The vector contains *copies* of all its callbacks, not references. And the function's parameter is a *copy* of the caller's function, not a reference. So the function in the vector will always be distinct from the parameter to the function. (Functions don't have values to compare.)

Comment: ahh shacks I thought so :( is there any workaround for this?

Comment: If they all have the same signature you could store them as C-style function pointers rather than using `std::function`.

Comment: If you're willing to give up on `std::function` and use plain function pointers, there is.

Comment: Generally it's not the job of the caller to care what the callbacks are. Those registering the callbacks can implement their use-specific way of addressing the problem.

Comment: or you can store these functions in some class and implement `==`

Comment: I suggest changing the design. Some times being able to register the same function more than once is useful (e.g. flush output buffers before and after all other callbacks).

Comment: (Off-topic) Since you're using C++11, could please you replace that `vector<std::function<void(void*)>>::iterator` with `auto`?

Comment: @KennyTM, that's what I did in my answer as well

Answer (score 2):

As noted in the comments the simplest solution is to use default C-style function pointers as they support `==` operator in opposite to C++11 `function` which does not.

```
using func_type = void(*)();
vector<func_type> _callbacks;

void Event::RegisterCallback(func_type callback)
{
    if (callback == nullptr)
       return;

    auto it = std::find(_callbacks.begin(), _callbacks.end(), callback);

    if (it == _callbacks.end()) {
        _callbacks.push_back(callback);
    }
    else {
        throw;
    }
}

void f() {};
void g() {};

/*
    evt.RegisterCallback(f); // works fine
    evt.RegisterCallback(g); // works fine
    evt.RegisterCallback(f); // throws exception
*/
```

If you don't like this approach you can write your own function-pointer class with support of equality operator.

Comment: seems it won't work with lambdas

Comment: I think you could use instead `vector<function<void()>>`

Answer (score 0):

Another solution is to have a class with a std::function member and another comperable member, and then overloading the () to get the std::function parameter and call it with the parameter, and the == operator to compeare the class using the comperable member.

CompareableFunction.h:

```
class CompareableFunction
{
public:
    CompareableFunction(int nId, std::function<void(parameter)> handler);
    ~CompareableFunction();

    void operator()(parameter param);

    bool operator== (CompareableFunction compareableFunc);

private:
    std::function<void(parameter)> m_handler;
    int m_nId;
};
```

CompareableFunction.cpp:

```
CompareableFunction::CompareableFunction(int nId, std::function<void(parameter)> handler)
{
    m_nId = nId;
    m_handler = handler;
}


CompareableFunction::~CompareableFunction()
{
}

void CompareableFunction::operator()(parameter param)
{
    return m_handler(param);
}

bool CompareableFunction::operator==(CompareableFunction compareableFunc)
{
    return (m_nId == compareableFunc.m_nId);
}
```

**EDIT:** you can convert the std::function to a C-style function pointer and use it to compare. example to a conversion is here: http://www.cplusplus.com/forum/general/63552/